# Can Java handle 10 Thread pool at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a Java Application which handles different region for example 10 regions.
Each region have different number of tasks.

I encounter a problem is that one particular region (`Region A`) have lots of tasks and the processing time of each task for that region is very long. Therefore, if I use a `Single Thread Pool`, and tasks of all region will be submitted to the `Single Thread Pool`, tasks of `Region A` will block other region 's tasks. Tasks of other region can only wait in the block queue until the tasks of `Region A` are finished.

I want to achieve if there are 5000 tasks of `Region A` submitted to `Single Thread Pool` , and each task is processing with a long time, other region tasks can be processed in parallel without being blocked by tasks of `Region A`.

I have a requirement which cannot create too much thread for the `Single Thread Pool`, and also `newCachedThreadPool()` is not recommended to use.

What my approach is to create 1 Thread Pool for each region, which will create 10 Thread Pool in total. But I do not know if there are any problems regarding multiple Thread Pool and if there are any other proper way to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processing capacity of running threads is always limited by the number of threads the hardware's CPU provides - keep that in mind when allocating threads to thread pools.

Use [`newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) for each region.

If your processing is mostly compute intensive, pick smaller sizes; perhaps `newFixedThreadPool(3)` for region A and `newFixedThreadPool(1)` for the others.

Chose larger numbers if your processing spends a lot of time waiting for processing external to the thread (eg web or db calls).

Experiment to see what provides acceptable liveliness.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say you're limited by the number of cores the CPU provides. If your application is spending a lot of time waiting for database/network, many threads will be waiting on a response, and the operating system can start running other threads.

Comment: @Kaia modified to use plainer grammar/vocabulary.

Comment: Note: `newFixedThreadPool(1)` is a special case. OP specifically said, "_single_ thread pool." That may mean that they want the tasks submitted to be performed one-by-one, in the order that the tasks were submitted. If that's the case, then using a thread "pool" with more than one worker would defeat that requirement.